# Retrieving data in codeigniter: passing variables but not identified

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I am new to PHP and codeigniter and I've been encountering a lot of PHP errors, such as `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and `Undefined variable: row and query`. In my views i tried to foreach it as `(query->results() as $row)` and the errors lesson to 1 which is an `undefined varaiable: query`

I'm not really sure which part I am missing, I already have declared query in my model, It seems that the controller was not able to receive the passed variable. Can anyone correct my mistake? and would give an explanation to avoid such mistakes in the future. Thanks!

Model function:

```
function getStudentInfo()
    {
          $this->db->select("firstname,middlename,lastname");
          $this->db->from('studentinfo');
          $query = $this->db->get();
          return $query->result();
    }
```

Controller function:

```
public function index() 
   {
          $this->data['query'] = $this->m_login->getStudentInfo(); //i passed the query to the data variable
          $this->load->view('v_home', $this->data);
   }
```

Views:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
   <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <h2>Welcome <?php echo $studentid; ?>!</h2>
   <a href="c_home/logout">Logout</a>

 <h4>Display Records From Database Using Codeigniter</h4>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
      <td><strong>Last Name</strong></td>
    </tr>
     <?php foreach($query as $row){?>
     <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row->firstname;?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row->lastname;?></td>
      </tr>    
     <?php }?>  
   </table>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Im not familiar with codeigniter, but you are passing the variable `data` in `$this->load->view('v_home', $this->data)` so in your view you prolly want to use `$data` instead of `$query`

Comment: 1. check $this->m_login->getStudentInfo(); any value
2. try use $data['query'] in controller, see what will happen

Comment: @Adimeus I also tried that, but data is also not identified.

Comment: @onegun tried 2, but the error is still the same.

Comment: At first glance, your code looks ok (aside of missing brackets in foreach in view).

Add few log_message to your controller to make sure you are really filling query variable: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

If that looks ok, pass entire view code, so we are able to examine it a bit closer.

Comment: for first point, pls do print_r($this->m_login->getStudentInfo()); or var_dump($this->m_login->getStudentInfo()); any value

Comment: @onegun performed point 1 now ` $this->data['query'] = print_r($this->m_login->getStudentInfo());` there was no value.

Comment: @IvanJovovic already pasted view code now

Comment: @NattyGuurl are you loading the `m_login` model before using it?

Comment: @NattyGuurl Can you post the url that you are heading your request to?
and one more thing, does your table `studentinfo` have data inside it?

Comment: I have inserted your view into my test CI app, it does not have issue with the undefined vars. Error is somewhere in controller, use log_message in your controller to make sure your $query is populated with data.

Comment: @Ibrahim.I yes there is data and this is the url:http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/c_home

Comment: @IvanJovovic I set up my log_message in config.php (am i doing it right?) after that I just add log_message in CI?

Comment: @NattyGuurl Here is the guide, at the bottom of the page: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

Comment: no need assign value. directly put print_r($this->m_login->getStudentInfo()); or var_dump($this->m_login->getStudentInfo()); if there is not value, it means $this->m_login->getStudentInfo() is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure seems ok.
You made following error.

```
<?php foreach($query as $row);?>//your foreach ends here for this comma
   //those lines are out of foreach
     <?php echo $row->firstname;?>//$row is undefined and $row->firstname is invalid property
     <?php echo $row->lastname;?>//same for lastname

 <?php ?>
```

use this way.

```
<?php foreach($query as $row){?>

     <?php echo $row->firstname;?>
     <?php echo $row->lastname;?>

 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thanks! it lessen the error however, $query is still an undefined variable :(

Comment: $query undefined. impossible unless you calling the view from different function without passing `$this->data['query']`.Make sure your are at right controller and function.

Comment: Is it possible that it is undefined because I have 3 controllers?

Comment: its not for 3 controllers.your current controller(the code you written at your question) should not produce this error.But if you call this view from other controller you also need send value like your current controllers index function doing